# Why can't the canvas element bind event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-canvas

Here is the code:

```
$('#insert_text').click(function(){
 var drawing_plate= $("#Drawing_Plate")[0];
 context = drawing_plate.getContext('2d');
 drawing_plate.bind('touchstart',insert_the_text);
});
```

I select the canvas element, assigning it to drawing_plate. But the Chromium complains that

`Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLCanvasElement> has no method 'bind`

But the drawing_plate is indeed a jQuery object, why doesn't it owns the method:
`.bind()`...?

UPDATE: Please give explanations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying  to call a method that is only available to a jQuery object with a DOM object. `Convert DOM object to jQuery object before calling jQuery object function`.

Change

```
 drawing_plate.bind('touchstart',insert_the_text);
```

to

```
 $(drawing_plate).bind('touchstart',insert_the_text);
```

Comment: Is drawing_plate here a DOM Object? And if I want to interchange DOM object with jQuery Object, do I just have to use '[0]' and '$()'  ?

Comment: Yes drawing_plate in your code is DOM object, yes again for interchanging you can use $() and []